# Exploiting technique POP RET doesn't work

Tags: security, exploit, shellcode

I've a virtual machine with Windows XP Professional SP3 x86 Spanish, and I've disabled DEP.

Well, I was executing the exploit POPPOPRET_JMPESP.pl for "Easy RM to MP3 Converter" (yes, the program of the tutorial Corelan), and didn't work, so I've done 2 tests:

The first, and successful, replacing the JMP ESP that jumps to the beginning of the shellcode, for "CCCC" (\x43\x43\x43\x43), and produce error trying to execute this direction.
[Source](http://pastebin.com/WkGkr8TU)
[Screenshot](http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/jmpesp-is-cccc-903645.jpg)

And the second, putting to the JMP ESP a valid direction and a shellcode that are many breakpoints. Here an error is produced due to the direction that the program has tried to execute, and JMP ESP NO points ONLY to the breakpoints put.
[Source](http://pastebin.com/rZcgE2wV)
[Screenshot](http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/shellcode-is-breakpoints-903658.jpg)

**The original stack is:**

---

Buffer will be filled with As

---

RET ADDRESSS will be substituted with the direction of a POP POP RET

---

4 bytes of junk will be substituted for "XXXX"

---

Here points ESP before it's executed the POP POP RET instructions, and
 it will be substituted with 4 NOPs

---

4 bytes of junk that it will be sustituted with 4 NOPs

---

4 bytes of junk where ESP will point after, and
 will be substited for a JMP ESP, and that will take of the stack
 the RET instruction we have put

---

Here is the beginning of the shellcode and is where will
 points the JMP ESP when be executed

---

Answer (score 0):

Are you correctly getting to your shellcode?

If yes, check your shellcode for any weird characters. That particular program will stop copying input at NULL characters (0x00) as well as a couple others. The easiest way to do this is find the last character in your shellcode that was copied correctly and excluding the one after that. You can use metasploit to generate shellcode excluding specific characters.

If no, check your offsets and padding.

Comment: See my new comment, please.